# AWS NAT Gateway Public IP Address for Whitelisting with Public Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-nat-gateway

I have an EC2 instance in a public subnet and I assigned an EIP to the instance and the IP address is Whitelisted to reach my company's network. The Instance must have a public IP address but I don't want to use EIP here. Whenever I restart the server the IP address is changing so I thought If I create a NAT Gateway and arrange the routeing table to use connect my company's network but when I do that I cannot reach the instance. NAT Gateway for the private network for but is there a way to set a static IP address to reach some places?

Default settings for the route table

[image]

Setting use NAT Gateway by default access did not work

[image]

Adding a new route for the company network did not work

[image]

Comment: If you put the instance in a public subnet and assigned it an EIP, the IP address should not change between reboots.  I suggest you change your question about getting that to work in the first place vs using a NAT Gateway where you don't need one.

Comment: I don't want to use EIP so that is the problem. I know If I keep the EIP and it won't change with the restart. `The Instance must have a public IP address but I don't want to use EIP here`

Comment: If you stop/start the EC2 instance it will lose its public IPv4 address. If you reboot it, it won't.

Comment: yes but I could stop and start it so my question is even the public IP changes how can the instance goes a corporate network with the nat gateway or similar product. with the static IP address without using EIP.

Answer (score 0):

To have a static IP address within AWS, you must use an Elastic IP.  Even if you use a NAT Gateway, it consumes an EIP.

From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html):

> You must also specify an Elastic IP address to associate with the NAT gateway when you create it.

Comment: I have to use EIP for NAT Gateway but I would use three EIP for 3 zones. Let's assume each zone has 50 instances then I have to use 150 EIP if I assign the IP address to the instances whereas with NAT I would use only 3 EIP. 

I can do it in private subnets my question is using a public subnet and assign a route to use NAT Gateway to reach a company network other traffic can use IGW. Please check the screenshots.

Comment: As-is, your question is only about a single EC2 host.  It might help if you explained the actual situation you are trying to address in your question.